# Js wrapped file upload request is returning empty array

Tags: reactjs, laravel, axios

I'm using React and Laravel. When I try to a post request for file upload with wrapped FormData object, a request getting empty array in Laravel. I want to use wrapping because I need to send multiple parameters.

It's well

```
function onSubmit() {    
    let array = gallery

    Axios.post(`/api/submit`, array).then(res => (
        console.log(res.data)
    ))
}
```

But it's getting empty array in backend

```
function onSubmit() { 
    let array = { gallery }

    Axios.post(`/api/submit`, array).then(res => (
        console.log(res.data)
    ))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hey you need to use a middleware in your node server to handle the files.

You can use multer. https://github.com/expressjs/multer

Comment: I'm using Laravel for backend, but I think this is the same problem.